# Node.js FileSystem access returns ENOENT despite the file existing

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a node.js function which uses fs.access to check if a file exists, is readable and writable:

```
function StackOverFlowFunction() {
try {
    fs.accessSync(`file://${__dirname}/config/config.ini`, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

despite the file EXISTING,

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'file:///home/callcenter1/BookGenerator/config/config.ini'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.accessSync (fs.js:248:11)
at Object.fs.accessSync (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:420:27)
at getConfig (/home/callcenter1/BookGenerator/main.js:12:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/callcenter1/BookGenerator/main.js:18:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: 'file:///home/callcenter1/BookGenerator/config/config.ini' }
```

I used the "Open Link" function from the Ubuntu terminal and it opened the file with gedit successfully.

What's the issue?

Edit 1:

I'm almost sure the path is right:

[image]

Comment: Do you check other file eg. in the same folder? I think you have wrong path.

Comment: I looks weird `file://${__dirname}/config/config.ini`.Can not you just use it that way: `${__dirname}/config/config.ini`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper filesystem path, without a scheme:

```
fs.accessSync(`${__dirname}/config/config.ini`, ...)
```

Comment: Electron's `win.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/app/app.html');` works just fine. Tried this anyway and the error still goes.

Comment: `win.loadURL()` loads a URL; `fs` is meant for filesystem actions.

Comment: The answer isn't yet complete because the solution will only actually fix the issue if `$(__dirname)` gets removed.

Comment: @Propolys I rejected that edit because it will not match the answer with the question. The path generated in your question (and the one giving the error) is _mostly_ correct, while still using `__dirname`. Are you sure you're using brackets (`${__dirname}`) and not parentheses (`$(__dirname)`).

Comment: It was a typo, meant to be `${__dirname}`. I think that the actual issue in the question was the fact that I expected node's filesystem to treat `${__dirname}` similar to electron's loadURL(). Which means that I thought ${__dirname} would be treated as the absolute path to the folder rather than the file:// URL.

Comment: @Propolys `__dirname` contains the absolute path of the directory of the `.js` file that calls it :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error message due to completely different reason. If you set path based on some env variables, this can happen because an extra   (space) added to the variable value on Windows. Then the message will look quite obscure, like an existing file you sure about does not exist:

```json
{ "errorMessage":"The file at x:\\path\\to\\file.ext  does not exist, or it is not a file. ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'x:\\path\\to\\file.ext '" }
```

Notice the    (double space) between `file.ext` and `does`.

I used syntax like

```sh
SET "VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE-WHERE-EXTRA-SPACE-CAUSES-ERROR";
```

to fix the issue. Found that here: https://superuser.com/a/1290292